# openpyxl заполняет всю оперативную память

Tags: python, openpyxl, big-data

Столкнулся с такой проблемой как полное заполнение оперативной памяти. Я написал скрипт который обрабатывает большую Excel таблицу с 200 тыс. строк и 58 столбцов.
Как видно на скриншоте простое открытие файла на запись заполняет 88% оперативной памяти. Если начать с ним работать перебирая/перезаписывая ячейки заполнение памяти может достигнуть до 99%.

Вопрос: как обрабатывая такую таблицу снизить потребление оперативной памяти?

[image: Системный монитор]

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию `openpyxl` сохраняет в оперативную память всю таблицу. Но вы можете использовать [оптимизированные режимы](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html), чтобы снизить потребление памяти:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='large_file.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['big_data']

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)

# Close the workbook after reading
wb.close()
```

Comment: Хорошо, с чтением разобрались. Что можно сделать с записью в файл??? Потому что открыв файл на запись - это займёт большой объём памяти...

Comment: @zomaman Аналогично чтению есть [Write-only mode](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html#write-only-mode) для записи

Comment: К сожалению параметр write_only есть только в классе Workbook, который создаёт новую книгу. Что делать с книгой, которая уже существует???

Comment: @zomaman Вы можете открыть существующую книгу в режиме чтения и параллельно открыть новую в режиме записи. Читаете часть данных, записываете в новую книгу. В конце сохраняете новую книгу под именем существующей

Answer (score 0):

Помимо использования оптимизированных режимов, вы можете периодически сохранять и заново открывать книгу. На этапе сохранения, `openpyxl` освободит используемые ресурсы:

```py
wb.save('large_file.xlsx')
wb = load_workbook('large_file.xlsx')
```

Comment: почему вы не совместили 2 ответа в один?

Comment: @iKuzmychov Потому что это 2 разных ответа. И связывает их только вопрос